# Agendar cita y guardar en archivo txt con Python

Tags: python

Necesito que el usuario elija día y hora. Hice un matriz con un horario de lunes a viernes y cada día hay citas disponibles.

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se agende una cita en la matriz diga "ocupado" y no se pueda agendar a otra persona, luego guardar esa matriz en un archivo txt, y luego cuando se quiera agregar otra cita, abra ese txt y repita el proceso anterior.

De ser posible, que le muestre los demás horarios disponibles de ese día y elija uno de esos días disponibles.

(Para este ejercicio NO puedo usar numpy, solo ciclos)

Este es mi código:

```
matriz_citas =[
     ["lunes","martes","miercoles","jueves","viernes"],
     ["7;00am","7;00am","7;00am","7;00am","7;00am"],
     ["8:00am","8:00am","8:00am","8:00am","8:00am"],
     ["9:00am","9:00am","9:00am","9:00am","9:00am"],
     ["10:00am","10:00am","10:00am","10:00am","10:00am"],
     ["11:00am","11:00am","11:00am","11:00am","11:00am"],
     ["1:00pm","1:00pm","1:00pm","1:00pm","1:00pm"],
     ["2:00pm","2:00pm","2:00pm","2:00pm","2:00pm"],
     ["3:00pm","3:00pm","3:00pm","3:00pm","3:00pm"]

#imprime la matriz de manera ordenada
for filas in matriz_citas:
        print ("[", end=" ")
        for elemento in filas:
            print(f"{elemento}", end="  ")
        print("]")

#Pregunta el dia la cita
print("""           [Selecciones el dia de su cita]
                            ***Sábado y Domingo CERRADO***

                            ***************************
                            *  [1] ------> Lunes      *
                            *  [2] ------> Martes     *
                            *  [3] ------> Miércoles  *
                            *  [4] ------> Jueves     *
                            *  [5] ------> Viernes    *
                            ***************************""")
optdia = input("Seleccione el dia de la cita: ")
if optdia == "1":
    dia = "Lunes"
elif optdia == "2":
    dia = "Martes"
elif optdia == "3":
    dia = "Miércoles"
elif optdia == "4":
    dia = "Jueves"
elif optdia == "5":
    dia = "Viernes"
else:
    input(("ERROR!!!\n" "No has pulsado ninguna opción correcta, pulsa ENTER para 
 continuar\n")) #!En caso de error

#Pregunta la jornada y la hora de cita
print("""             [Seleccione la jornada y la hora]
                    ***********************************************
                    *    [Durante el dia]     [Durante la tarde]  *
                    *  [1] ------> 7:00am  |  [8] ------> 2:00pm  *
                    *  [2] ------> 8:00am  |  [9] ------> 4:00pm  *
                    *  [3] ------> 9:00am  |  [10] ------> 5:00pm *
                    *  [4] ------> 10:00am |                      *
                    *  [5] ------> 11:00am |                      *
                    *  [6] ------> 1:00pm  |                      *
                    *  [7] ------> 2:00pm  |                      *
                    ***********************************************""")
cita_horario = input("Seleccione la jornada y la hora para su cita: ")
if cita_horario == "1":
    hora = "7:00am"
    jornada = "durante el dia"
elif cita_horario == "2":
    hora = "8:00am"
    jornada = "durante el dia"
elif cita_horario == "3":
    hora = "9:00am"
    jornada = "durante el dia"
elif cita_horario == "4":
    hora = "10:00am"
    jornada = "durante el dia"
elif cita_horario == "5":
    hora = "11:00am"
    jornada = "durante el dia"
elif cita_horario == "6":
    hora = "1:00pm"
    jornada = "durante el dia"
elif cita_horario == "7":
    hora = "2:00pm"
    jornada = "durante el dia"
elif cita_horario == "8":
    hora = "2:00pm"
    jornada = "durante la tarde"
elif cita_horario == "9":
    hora = "3:00pm"
    jornada = "durante la tarde"
elif cita_horario == "10":
    hora = "4:00pm"
    jornada = "durante la tarde"
else:
    input(("ERROR!!!\n" "No has pulsado ninguna opción correcta, pulsa ENTER para 
continuar\n")) #!En caso de error
```

Answer (score 0):

Para empezar, yo guardaría en las variables `dia` y `hora`, el índice de estas en la matriz, para poder trabajar más cómodamente:

```
if optdia == "1":
    dia = 0
elif optdia == "2":
    dia = 1
elif optdia == "3":
    dia = 2
...

if cita_horario == "1":
    hora = 1
    jornada = "durante el dia"
elif cita_horario == "2":
    hora = 2
    jornada = "durante el dia"
...
```

Para continuar, para cargar y guardar los datos puedes usar la librería `json`, al principio del programa, puedes cargar los datos:

```
import json

with open('datos.json') as f:
   data = json.load(f)
```

Después, asumiendo que data es un array de tuplas, y que cada una de estas tuplas contiene los índices `dia` y `hora`, puedes filtrar `matriz_citas` antes de mostrarlo, para mostrar los horarios ocupados:

```
for dia, hora in data:
    matriz_citas[hora][dia] = 'ocupado'

for filas in matriz_citas:
    print ("[", end=" ")
    ...
```

Por último, al acabar el programa, se comprueba si el horario seleccionado estaba ya ocupado y se guardan los nuevos datos:

```
if [dia, hora] in data:
    print('El horario seleccionado ya está ocupado')
else:
    data.append([dia, hora])
    with open('datos.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```

Para que funcione, sobra decir, que tendrás que crear previamente el fichero `datos.json` y su contenido debe ser `[]`

Si como has comentado, tampoco puedes usar la librería json, tendrás que cargar y guardar los datos tu manualmente, por ejemplo, para guardar los datos podrías hacer algo como:

```
def save(data, file):
    for dia, hora in data:
        file.write(f'{dia} {hora}\n')
```

Y para cargar los datos guardados:

```
def load(file):
    res = []
    for line in file.readlines():
        entry = line.split()
        res.append(list(map(int, entry)))
    return res
```

Ahora solo tendrías que sustiyuir las funciones json, por estas y si quieres cambiar la extensión del archivo, de `.josn` a `.txt`

Comment: No me permiten usar json, ni importar nada, solo me permiten usar ciclos

Comment: @RouryRamirez, he añadido una modificación para no usar json, ¿con ese método te vale?